# How to position checkbox with image?

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox and right next to that is image. I want be able to click on image to check the checkbox. I found out it can be done by wrapping the image and checkbox with label tag.

However, I need to position the checkbox somewhere else than it is by default. Don't you know how to do that?

Comment: "Somewhere else" is rather vague.

Comment: Does it matter? Somewhere else might be everywhere, but not where it is by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `label for`.
Your checkbox.

```
<input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
```

And then put the image wherever you need to:

```
<label for="checkbox1"><img src="your image path" /></label>
```